How to import csv file which contains into table which have json columns
I am trying to import csv data in table using below command
COPY table1(col1,col2,col3) from 'file:///home/tab.csv' WITH (format= 'csv' , delimiter = ',') RETURN SUMMARY;
I am not getting any kind of error but in col3 it is getting stored as "," seprated.
unable to store data properly in CrateDB.
Data types of columns
col1 - int
col2 - text
col3 - Object
Below is sample data which is in csv
in col3 there is json data.
123, 
customer_table,
{
  "Columns": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "PROTOCOL_MESSAGE",
      "DataType": "VARCHAR2",
      "IsSensitive": "N",
      "Justification": "abc",
      "PIITypes": [
        
      ],
      "RandomDataElements": [
        "None"
      ],
      "RiskScore": 0.1
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "DP_WARNINGS1",
      "DataType": "VARCHAR2",
      "IsSensitive": "N",
      "Justification": "abc",
      "PIITypes": [
        
      ],
      "RandomDataElements": [
        "None"
      ],
      "RiskScore": 0.1
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "DB_UNIQUE_NAME",
      "DataType": "VARCHAR2",
      "IsSensitive": "N",
      "Justification": "abc",
      "PIITypes": [
        
      ],
      "RandomDataElements": [
        "XE"
      ],
      "RiskScore": 0.1
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "OBJECT_TYPE",
      "DataType": "NUMBER",
      "IsSensitive": "N",
      "Justification": "abc",
      "PIITypes": [
        
      ],
      "RandomDataElements": [
        "0"
      ],
      "RiskScore": 0.1
    }
  ],
  "IsSensitive": "Y",
  "NumRows": 82,
  "RiskScore": 0.7,
  "SensitiveColumnCount": 4,
  "TableName": "AUD$UNIFIED",
  "Tag": "XYZ",
  "TotalColumnCount": 109
}

